# Teamcity How to: Ignore inspection of third party files

Tags: teamcity

In Teamcity 2017, how can I skip inspection of a set of third party files?
I tried the following ways: 
1. Added the DotSettings in advanced configuration to skip these files by going to Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings and adding these files

[image: DotSettings Inspect Code in settings]

2. Tried to add these files in third party code in ReSharper on desktop (adds the lines to dotsettings too ) by going to Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> Third Party Code in Visual Studio 2015

[image: Third Party code exclusion]

How can I get the inspect to ignore these files?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rob, I added additional instructions, but please let me know how to improve the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked through the issue to get a solution.

When ReSharper Options screen is invoked from Visual Studio Top navigation: ReSharper->Options, we have two places to add the files or directories to be skipped.

1. If we need the symbols for other files, we put them in the Third-Party Libabry Code under the Left navigation options: Code-Editing>Third-Party Code[image: See Window selection option in the image here]
2. If we do not need the symbols to be loaded, we can add them under Code Inspection>Settings Image for this is as shown: 
   [image: Exclude in Settings - no symbols needed]

Once either step is done, the important thing is to share this with the team 
by clicking on Save To button and then selecting the Team section as shown below.

[image]

This adds the files and folders to be excluded in the DotSettings file in the solution. I was accidentally adding to my own personal settings file - called the DotSettings.user file.

Once the file is checked into the solution as a build item, the DotSettings (Not DotSettings.user) is used in the teamcity build to exclude the files we dont need inspected.